# On XML, keep lines with a particular name and delete others

Tags: xml

I'm looking for a solution to extract lines containing a particular criterion in an xml.

Here is an example of a line:

```
<sms protocol="0" address="+33617364286" date="1487432293748" type="1" subject="null" body="Mais nan !  On est en train de lézarder au soleil sous une cabane de pecheur ! C'est joli chez toi " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+33609002960" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1487432292000" readable_date="18 févr. 2017 16:38:13" contact_name="Clémence Lerondeau" />
```

I would like to keep only the lines containing the criterion:

```
contact_name="XXX"
```

Thank you in advance, and sorry I'm a very, very new developer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify some terms first.  I am assuming by "line" you mean an XML element?  You did not specify what programming language you will be using.  Most of them all have support for parsing XML, and in particular, XPath support.  Assuming that is the case, then an XPath expression such as below would work.

```
/sms[@contact_name= 'Clémence Lerondeau']
```

should suffice (replace hard-coded name with a parameter )  Spend some time reading about [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

Comment: Thks OldProgrammer. I don't know XPath, is it easy for a beginner?

Comment: I installed XPath extension to sublime text. Can you help me on how to do my job? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you I can reach the first line containing my parameter. But I want to display all the lines containing this parameter.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a personal tutoring site.